# Debian 10 - static route doesn't override default

Tags: linux, networking, routing, lxc, iproute2

My /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wan
iface wan inet static
        address $myPublicIP
        netmask $ispSubnet
        gateway $ispGateway

auto vpn
iface vpn inet static
        address 10.102.1.194
        netmask 255.255.255.192
        up ip route add 192.168.10.32/27 via 10.102.1.196 dev vpn src 10.102.1.194 metric 10
        up ip route add 192.168.11.0/24 via 10.102.1.196 dev vpn src 10.102.1.194 metric 10
```

`ip r` shows as expected:

```
default via $wanGateway dev wan onlink 
$wanGateway/$wanCIDR dev wan proto kernel scope link src $wanIP 
10.102.1.192/26 dev vpn proto kernel scope link src 10.102.1.194 
192.168.10.32/27 via 10.102.1.196 dev vpn src 10.102.1.194 metric 10 
192.168.11.0/24 via 10.102.1.196 dev vpn src 10.102.1.194 metric 10
```

But even after reboot, traffic goes via LAN (a.k.a `vpn`) gateway, 10.102.1.193/27:

```
traceroute to 192.168.11.2 (192.168.11.2), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.102.1.193 (10.102.1.193)  368.435 ms  368.370 ms  368.316 ms^C
```

This is Debian 10 LXC container under Proxmox VE 6.0-9. Is it the culprit, or am I missing something there? I tried [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321687/w), but it didn't work for some reason - adding table and/or ip rule doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: What is the expected outcome then? And what do you get from `ip route get 192.168.11.2` & `ip route show match 192.168.11.2`?

Comment: Not sure if it matters but why do they have `metric`?

Comment: @grawity 192.168.X traffic goes via 10.102.1.196 gateway (which is connected to SSTP server 10.102.1.193.

Comment: @Tom Yan I wanted to check if metric override would do the trick. Seems not.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that there's no route that has `10.102.1.193` as gateway being listed in `ip r`, and the fact that the interface name is `vpn`, makes me wonder if it's actually a `tun` (or anything of level/layer 3). In that case the `via` part of the routes wouldn't make a difference as there's no ARP/MAC involved.

For example with OpenVPN (with tun), the way to use a client as gateway is to enable `client-to-client` and add corresponding `iroute` for a `route` pushed (or configured on a client), so that the VPN server will know where (i.e. which client) to direct the traffics (instead of "letting it out" on its own host).

Though the VPN appears to be a multi-client setup, with that and OpenVPN you don't usually configure address in this way (as in fact, it requires you set `iroute` for the address, otherwise the server wouldn't even response to you ping through the tunnel). So perhaps this is purely my wild guess (or you are doing everything wrong).

Comment: This container is located inside 10.102.1.192/27 VLAN behind Mikrotik CHR, and the 10.102.1.196 is another site, connected via SSTP, and input/output/forwarding firewall rules enabled on it (196).

Comment: @ivdok what does `ip l show vpn` give anyway?

Comment: 422: vpn@if423: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3e:a4:ab:e7:8f:f9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0

Comment: What about `ip r show via 10.102.1.193 table all`?

Comment: It returns nothing.

Comment: What does `ip neigh` give (after you ping both `10.102.1.193` and `10.102.1.196`)?

Comment: `10.102.1.193 dev vpn lladdr ca:ec:17:d4:64:cc REACHABLE
10.102.1.196 dev vpn lladdr ca:ec:17:d4:64:cc PROBE
10.102.1.195 dev vpn lladdr ca:ec:17:d4:64:cc REACHABLE
`

Comment: Well it looks like "Mikrotik CHR" claims every addresses in `10.102.1.192/26` (or `/27`, the info you provided was inconsistent) with ARP. Do you have some really nasty setup there? You can `ip neigh flush dev vpn` and see if it makes a difference, but I bet it won't. Also, I am not sure if SSTP VPN can actually work on layer 2 (like OpenVPN with `tap`) or have "replacement for switching" (like `iroute` in OpenVPN). From what I read, it does not allow site-to-site communications.

Comment: The thing is - this GW router doesn't know about this subnet either, and forwards it further into the ISP network, but I digress. And I can't make static route on it either because it may affect other users (/26 is due to VLAN segregation). So what the hell do I do here?

Comment: I don't really get what you are talking about to be honest. But you need to figure out why `ca:ec:17:d4:64:cc` (whatever it is) claims it owns a bunch of addresses (if not every) with ARP. And then you need to make sure the SSTP connection actually emulates layer 2 / can carry Ethernet frames. I suppose a physical interface needs to be bridged together with the SSTP interface, otherwise it would be a mess anyway if you actually configure them to be in the same subnet (when they are actually not).